# Jasmine - Test a simple initialization function

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, tdd, karma-runner, code-coverage

I'm starting with Karma and Jasmine for Unit Testing. I'm with my first real test and I want to know if I'm doing good.

I have this method that calls three initialization functions.

```
myApp.initializer.initializeApp = function () {
    myApp.initializer.eventDelegation();
    myApp.initializer.initializeGlobals();
    myApp.scrollManager.initialize();  
};
```

---

If I make no test, Karma-Coverage tells me that initializeApp is not covered, so I want to make a test to validate to see if all is correct. What kind of test is necessary? if I write these two different test, Karma-coverage tells me function is now covered.

```
describe ("Initializations suite", function(){
    it ("must check if functions are defined before call them", function(){
      spyOn(myApp.initializer, "eventDelegation");
      myApp.initializer.initializeApp();
      expect(myApp.initializer.eventDelegation).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

or

```
describe ("Initializations suite", function(){
   it ("must check if functions are defined before call them", function(){
      expect(myApp.initializer.initializeApp).not.toThrow();
   });
});
```

Both test make the initializeApp as covered, but as I said, I don't know what's the proper way to test this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be NOT to `spyOn` `myApp.initializer.eventDelegation();` and then expect a few things the method is supposed to do.

We generally `spyOn` methods that are not present in the file we want to test. For example, if I'm writing test cases for an angularjs controller file that depends on a service, then I'll `spyOn` the service's method that has been called within my controller.

What you've done in the above test is, mocked a method that's already present in the file. A better way would be to call `myApp.initializer.initializeApp` and expect `myApp.initializer.eventDelegation();` to have been called. Also make sure to expect as much behaviour as you can. That'll improve the quality of your  test cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Siddath ajmera. What I understand in your answer is that is correct to have both test due to cover more behaviour, and in the first test simply remove the spyOn?